# Python: How can I know the position of a modifier in the stack?

Tags: scripting, modifiers

For example in the following case, the Armature modifier should have a position index of 0 and the Subdivision a position index of 1. How can I get this index?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blender's collections don't support indexing (although support could be added).

So the simplest way is to convert to a list:

`index = list(ob.modifiers).index(mod)`

If you need to access indices multiple times you could create a table:

```
modifier_index_map = {mod: i for (i, mod) in enumerate(ob.modifiers)}

index = modifier_index_map[modifier]
```

If your not sure the modifier is in the map:

```
index_or_none = modifier_index_map.get(modifier)
```